# Algoritmo recursivo

Tags: java

Estou com um trabalho na faculdade que eu simplesmente não tenho ideia de por onde começar.

**Apresentar a funçãao matematica recursiva que define o mdc (maximo divisor comum)
entre dois naturais. Com base nela, fazer:
1. Definir um algoritmo recursivo para computar o mdc e ilustra-lo com pelo menos um
exemplo de computação.**

Alguém pode me traduzir este texto? Porque nao sei o que fazer..

Comment: Você sabe como se calcula o mdc?

Comment: Decompondo os dois numeros em multiplicacoes de primos não é? Dai multiplica os numeros primos em comum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem, recursivamente o código fica bem pequeno; lembrando que a recursão deve ter um valor de retorno que a pare caso tal valor seja atingido, senão, a recursão irá continuar a fazer a substituição (lembrando também que, na substituição, algum valor deverá mudar, caso contrário corre o risco de loop infinito.):

**Exemplo de Computação (Código Java, por exemplo):**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MDC{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a, b;

        System.out.print("Digite dois inteiros: ");

        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Máximo divisor comum: %d\n", calcularMdc(a, b));
    }

    static int calcularMdc(int a, int b){

        // Se o novo valor tiver módulo zero, 
        // imprime b("a" depois da primeira vez)
        if ( a == 0 ) 
            return b;

        // Substitui na função, em "a",
        // o valor do resto da divisão de "b" por "a",
        // pois enquanto esse resto não for zero, e também
        // "a" não zerar ele irá continuar o loop.
        // (pois para iteração anteiror, o valor de "a"
        //  será o menor possível, portanto a fração a maior possível)
        return calcularMdc( b % a, a );
    }
}
```

Para o algoritmo basta traduzir a função `calcularMdc` em portugol, fluxograma, ou algo do tipo. Acho que é isso que seu professor está querendo. Qualquer coisa leve o código.

É interessante notar, ainda no código, que os valores podem ser inseridos em quaisquer ordem, pois na chamada recursiva há troca de lado dos parâmetros, que vai sempre sendo substituindo, até a condição ser atingida.

Comment: perfeito! Saberia informar como ficaria esse algoritmo com recursão na cauda?

Comment: Já é recursiva em cauda. Não tem necessidade de construir outra função de apoio para eliminar qualquer operação no return. Ela já retorna ela própria.